# Getting all redis zset elements

Tags: node.js, redis

I use [node-georedis](https://github.com/arjunmehta/node-georedis) to get nearby locations. My location set will look like below,

```
{ key:
  { latitude: 10.322456,
    longitude: 10.233233,
    area: "some",
    .....
  }
},
{ key:
  { latitude: 10.432456,
    longitude: 10.333233,
    area: "some",
    .....
  }
},
```

By using `nearby`, I get the proper sorted order of keys like below,

```
{ 
  latitude: 10.322456,
  longitude: 10.233233,
  key: some key,
  hash: 122515
} 
{
  latitude: 10.432456,
  longitude: 10.333233,
  key: some key,
  hash: 122534
}
```

Now how to get the other data's also like area and so on? I tried using `ZRANGE 1 -1 WITHSCORES` but it just returns key and hashes since my data type is `zset`.

Need help with this. Thanks in advance.